# Как добавить изображение на Button?

Tags: android

Мне нужно, чтобы картинка оказалась над button как сделать?
Местами их уже менял не знаю, что еще сделать, чтобы кнопка оказалась под картинкой.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="235dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Настройки"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="67dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/statusAnswer"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/v_button_b"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/v_button_b"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="260dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="77dp" />
```

Comment: Для чего может понадобиться кнопка под картинкой?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы на кнопке была не большая картинка в углу. А button не дает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно делать ImageView поверх кнопки. Нужно просто добавить изображение на саму кнопку одним из аттрибутов `drawableRight`|`drawableLeft`|`drawableTop`|`drawableBottom`|`drawableEnd`|`drawableStart`:

```
<Button

  android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_icon"


 />
```

Answer (score 2):

Используй вместо Button - ImageButton.
Если нужно просто добавить иконку в кнопку, то лучше использовать параметр "drawable[left, right...]"

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/v_button_b"
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, тогда текста не будет(( А он тоже нужен

Comment: Обновил ответ. Думаю такое решение вам подойдет.